# JSON Creation from Java

Tags: java, json, org.json

HI I am new to JSON and I have to create the below JSON from Java.

```
{{ "TESTMAIN" : { "TEST1" : { "384" : "250", "96" : "450" },
           "TEST2" :{ "384" : "5", "96" : "10" },
           "TEST3" : "256",
           "TEST4" : "T" }
```

I have created each object using JSONObject.put. But how to combine the 4 TEST objects with the text TESTMAIN. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The json library is awfully verbose, this should do what you need:

```
final JSONObject wrapper = new JSONObject();
final JSONObject inner = new JSONObject();
final JSONObject innersub1 = new JSONObject();
innersub1.put("384", "250");
innersub1.put("96", "450");
final JSONObject innersub2 = new JSONObject();
innersub2.put("384", "5");
innersub2.put("96", "10");
inner.put("TEST1", innersub1);
inner.put("TEST2", innersub2);
inner.put("TEST3", "256");
inner.put("TEST4", "T");
wrapper.put("TESTMAIN", inner);
System.out.println(wrapper.toString());
```

I would advise you to look at more modern JSON libraries like Gson or Jackson, because they make life a lot simpler!

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you're doing this by hand?  There is a JSON library for Java that can do this for you.

[JSON in Java](http://www.json.org/java/), it has APIs for creating objects, arrays, etc. It will also serialize and deserialize JSON.

Comment: I use [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/), which is as the name implies - simple :)

Comment: See section 2-3 of their examples.  That covers how to use a List implementation to add an array.

Comment: any sample code to form the above JSON using the libraries.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need a [JSONArray](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html).

Comment: Nope, a JSONArray will create square brackets. He needs nested JSONObjects.